# Traceback error when using a counter function

Tags: python

I want to do the following:

1. Read in a text file.
2. Check line by line to see if words match words in a taglist.
3. Create a frequency count of the list

Therefore I have the following:

```
tagList = {"later", "test"}
aList = [];
tagCount = {}
from collections import Counter

#Sample
f = ["This is a test", "Call me later"]
for line in f:
    fields = line.split(' ')
    for word in fields:
        if word in tagList:
            list = aList.append([word])

counts = Counter(aList)
```

It all works fine till the counts part. When I do this i throws the following error. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marc/PycharmProjects/clustering/load.py", line 51, in <module>
   counts = Counter(aList)
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 530, in __init__
   self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 617, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `aList.append(word)` without the square braces

Comment: devil is in the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are counting a *list of lists*. Each element in `aList` is itself a list, with one word in it:

```
list = aList.append([word])
```

You are appending `[word]` to the list there, so a list with one element.

A `Counter` tries to use each list as a key, which is not possible because list objects are mutable and thus not hashable.

You don't want to count lists, you want to count *words*, so append just the word without a surrounding list:

```
aList.append(word)
```

Note that the `list =` part can and should be dropped. `.append()` returns `None`, always, as the list is altered in-place, and you never use `list` anywhere else in your code.